# Can 'clustering' and 'alwayson failover clustering' be used interchangeably?

Tags: availability-groups, clustering

I am reading this summary from the book 'Pro SQL Server 2019 Administration' from Carter.

In 'hot', when citing the examples the author writes 'Clustering'.

[image]

But when each technology is explained it is listed as 'AlwaysOn failover clustering'... My question is about naming: can the terms 'clustering' and 'alwayson failover clustering' be used interchangeably? or do they  mean different things?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends in which context `Clustering` term is used

If we are talking about SQL Server, then `Clustering` means `AlwaysOn Failover Clustering`
When we are talking about Windows, `Clustering` means `Windows Server Failover Cluster`

> My question is about naming: can the terms 'clustering' and 'alwayson failover clustering' be used interchangeably?

I would say - yes, these terms can be used interchangeably - BUT, you have to make sure you and whoever you are holding conversation with, understand in which context you use term `Clustering` - Windows or SQL Server

Comment: It's also often used (incorrectly) to refer to Availability Groups. Even when the context of SQL Server is clear, it can be a confusing term without full context to clarify AG or FCI

Comment: @AMtwo yes it is, it can be confusing. However, author is asking whether if  'clustering' can be used to mean FCI, and I say yes because I've seen examples and Peter Carter book screenshot is one of them :) Whether it is ambiguous or not is a different story :) I agree that more specific terms like AOAG, AOFCI, WSFC should be used though.  Whoever down voted I would be grateful if you remove

Answer (score 1):

"Clustering" is definitely used here to refer to SQL Server's Failover Cluster Instances (FCIs). However, the terms are not interchangeable.

Both FCIs and Availability Groups (AGs) are built on top of Windows Server Failover Clusters (WSFCs). I've seen FCIs, AGs, and WDFCs referred to as "Clusters" or "Clustering."  The correctness of referring to any of these simply as "Clustering" is debatable.

What isn't debatable is that **referring to any of those technologies simply as "Clustering" is ambiguous and can be confusing without proper context**. Using the more verbose terminology, or even in abbreviations will always be unambiguous.